# Is it possible to change backround color of editor and autocomplete tooltips in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, text-editor, color-scheme

I changed color scheme for Visual Studio, setting a background color to black. Also I use Visual Assis to enhance color syntax. Now code looks great, but autocompletion list and editor tooltip are shown on the default white background. WIth new color scheme it looks awful.

In `Completion list` and `Editor tooltip` I can't change enything except font size - colors are disabled. Is it possible to change colors anyway?

I use VS 2008.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resharper has a different looking Intellisense and Editor tooltip than what usually comes with Visual Studio. The only way I know of changing that stuff is to write your own provider and designing them yourself. Probably not worth the effort.

Comment: As MS says, both Resharper and Visual Assist team have rewritten built-in editor to make highlighting because versions prior to 2010 did not support such customizations.