# Is there plugins/addons for visual studio 2010 to change the code and text editor's background color?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have been looking for , lets use the word "mods", for visual studio left and right to be able to change the background and font color of the code editor for quite a while now. This is a simple question and hopefully not a duplicate of [Is it possible to change backround color of editor and autocomplete tooltips in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2181494/is-it-possible-to-change-backround-color-of-editor-and-autocomplete-tooltips-in). If I can refine my question a bit more, is it possible to manually change the background color of the code and text editor, or does mods or plugins or addons exist somewhere to do this feature for me? My eyes are straining on the white background...

I am using visual studio 2010

Comment: Is it me, or are you simply looking for Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Fonts and Colors?

Comment: Checking it out. I never found it :?

Comment: just for fonts, line numbers, indicator margins etc.  not for the actual background (want to make mine dark grey, easier on my eyes)

Comment: Added an answer which, I think, will work for you ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the main menu, go to  Tools -> Options. From there open up Environment -> Fonts and Colors. If you don't want to spent the time configuring it that way (which would be **completely** understandable), download the [theme editor](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/20cd93a2-c435-4d00-a797-499f16402378/), or pick and download a nice theme at http://studiostyl.es/

Comment: That hits the spot. Thanks, gonna check how to install a theme now